# Parsing XML data

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-2.7, xml-parsing

im parsing this very simple xml file:

```
<root>
    <shelter>
        <adress>21 אחד העם</adress>
        <code>א-1</code>
        <lon></lon>
        <lat></lat>
    </shelter>
    <shelter>
        <adress>13 שלח</adress>
        <code>10 - א</code>
        <lon></lon>
        <lat></lat>
    </shelter>
    <shelter>
        <adress>ביאליק</adress>
        <code>11 - א</code>
        <lon></lon>
        <lat></lat>
    </shelter>
    <shelter>
        <adress>9 מוריה</adress>
        <lon></lon>
        <lat></lat>
    </shelter>
    <shelter>
        <adress>58 בזל</adress>
        <lon></lon>
        <lat></lat>
    </shelter>
</root>
```

And i'm using this piece of simple code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
pars = et.XMLParser(encoding='Windows-1255')
tree = et.parse('NewFile.xml',parser=pars)
root = tree.getroot()
for shelter in root.findall('shelter'):
    adress = shelter.find('adress').text
    print adress
```

I'm getting this error:"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: character maps to undefined"

As you can probably tell the text is in hebrew and i'm guessing thats where my error is coming from - or lack of understanding what 'encoding' **means**. 
I've looked up different discussions about parsing and encoding issues but none have adressed the issue of foreign language handeling.

Regards.

Comment: Does using `encoding='utf-8'` solve the issue?

Comment: i tried it. it doesnt work(same error).

Comment: You have to discover the encoding in which the file is saved. Basically, to go from unicode to bytes you **encode** the characters. That means you choose a specific encoding which maps certain characters to certain bytes sequences. On the other hand, to go from bytes to unicode, you **decode** the bytes. That means using an encoding that knows how to transform the bytes into meaningful characters. But if you don't know the encoding in which the file is saved, you're out of luck and have to guess.

Comment: I think that the error you got means that the encoding doesn't know how to map certain characters.

Comment: thanks, ill keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting no error, when trying to run your code.
The problem is probably in your file's encoding. Make sure it is **utf-8**. And also use `encoding="utf-8"`.

Comment: So i've figured what the problem was - i was editing and running my file using eclipse and the eclipse console does not support hebrew.